# Does delegates works with Constructors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have come across a code where I see method return type as `Func<T, TResult>` and I am amazed to see the object that is returned by this method is of Type `EFRepository`, where `EFRepository` is a Generic Class, and `EFRepository` constructor accepts an Instance of `DbContext` class.

```
protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>() where T : class
{
    return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
}
```

EFRepository Class:

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

please can someone explain what is going on here....

Comment: What I don't understand is, for the lambda expression, at which point does parameter `dbContext` get initialized?

Comment: @StevenLiekens People can put in what they like for the parameter when they call (invoke) the `Func<,>` there. For example: `var theFunc = DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<SomeClass>(); object output = theFunc(THEY_PUT_WHAT_THEY_LIKE_HERE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
}
```

What is returned is a *lambda* (see the arraow `=>`). The lambda is an anonymouys function that represents a method that takes in a `DbContext` and returns an `object`, hence the type `Func<DbContext, object>`.

In your lambda the incoming parameter is called `dbContext` (before arrow), and the object returned (after arrow) is of type `EFRepository<T>`. Every `EFRepository<>` is an `object` because `object` is the base class of `EFRepository<>`. So when you return a `EFRepository<>` you are in fact returning an `object` as required by the `Func<DbContext, object>`.

The lambda arrow is just like this named method:

```
static object NamedMethod<T>(dbContext)
    where T : class
{
    return new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
}
```

which could have been used like this:

```
protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return NamedMethod<T>;
}
```

Comment: can You please tell me one more thing, in this line

    `return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);`

we see dbContext, but it is not declared else where, so how he knows that `dbContext` refers to the `DbContext` class?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal It can tell because you say `return`, and the return type is `Func<DbContext, object>`, therefore it knows the signature must be "one argument of type `DbContext`". In other cases one will specify the type explicitly, it looks like this: `(DBContext dbContext) => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a delegate to a constructor. Instead you can have a delegate which creates an object by calling new.

In your code `DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory` returns a lambda expression. The lambda expression takes a `DBContext` and creates a object. You'd end up calling it a bit like this:

```
var repositoryFactory = DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<MyClass>()
var myOject = repositoryFactory(dbContext);
```